# Can I install conda packages with pip?

Tags: python, pip, conda, python-packaging, python-install

I want to install a package on macOS, which can be done by

`conda env create -f environment.yaml`
`conda activate <package>`

but I don't want to install `conda` and am looking for an alternative to install it with `pip` or `source` commands.

I tried `source env create -f environment.yaml`, and it errors out as `/usr/bin/env:1: parse error near ')'`.

If possible, I am looking for an alternative to install `conda` packages with `pip`.

Comment: No, pip can only handle Python packages - it has no knowledge of 3rd party packaging systems. If you're ok with using just native Python packaging, see the official [Python Packaging Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/) for how to get started

Comment: Duplicate is talking about Conda's `requirements.txt`, but it equally holds for the YAML format. Either 1) recreate the environment in a sandbox then run `pip list --format freeze` or 2) manually convert the YAML to a Pip-compatible `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score -1):

you can install Python packages directly using pip.
Create a virtual environment and install packages from a requirements file

```
python3 -m venv myenv
source myenv/bin/activate
pip install -r environment.yaml
```

You need to replace myenv with your desired virtual environment name and environment.yaml with the name of your requirements file.